# Burninate request for tag: webshperemq

Tags: support, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [webshperemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webshperemq) is a misspelling of the brand name "WebSphere". The product in question was WebSphere MQ and as of a recent IBM branding change is now called IBM MQ. We have a thriving community under the ibm-mq tag and websphere-mq is the properly spelled alias to it. User @JoshMc and I are working on re-tagging the questions now so the tag can be deleted without migration.

Comment: Ok, that's good, but you have no request here. If you're already retagging, what was the point of this post :P

Comment: Didn't realize the tag would "fade away."  How long would that take?  Would new questions against it extend its life?  If so would we not be a bit more hostile to things that are clearly misspelled?

Comment: Yeah, after inactivity they fade away. You can, IIRC, blacklist a tag so it can't be used, ensuring removal. Usually, not many questions are tagged with typos so just doing a few retags will allow it to fade away.

Comment: It's low volume.  I'll subscribe to it and if any more questions get asked before it fades away I'll revisit and ask for more help.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If a tag has no questions at 3:00 UTC, it will be deleted. It can then only be created again by a 1500+ rep user. Tags can be blacklisted if they prove to be a persistent problem and are harmful to the site. Blacklisting a tag stops that tag from being added to any questions, in turn stopping the tag from being created if all questions containing the tag have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail, @TinyGiant!  I was afraid "fade away" meant months or something.  Just glad this tag was so lightly trafficked so retagging was possible..